# What are the hidden objectives in the Parallel Quests of DragonBall Xenoverse?

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse

Each Parallel Quest has hidden objectives, what is the list of hidden objectives for each of the Parallel Quest ?

Comment: I think there's something like 97-100 Parallel Quests in the game at the moment. That'd be quite a sizeable list, and possibly too long for this sort of format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 55 Parallel Quests, and you can find the Optional Objectives here:

http://shinigaming.com/2015/03/04/dragon-ball-xenoverse-parallel-quest-guide/

List of all Parallel quests and their hidden conditions:

```
#0 – “Parallel Quest Tutorial”:

Hidden condition 1: Defeat all Saibamen
Hidden condition 2: Defeat Raditz
#1 – “World tournament Tag Team”:

Hidden condition 1: < 5 min
Hidden condition 2: Defeat Piccolo
#2 – “Prepare for the Attack of the Saiyans!”:

Hidden condition 1: < 5 min
Hidden condition 2: Defeat Goku
#3 – “Saiyan Blood”:

Hidden Condition 1: Raditz Health > 50%
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Gohan
#4 – “Saibamen’s Revenge”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 5 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Nappa
#5 – “Attack of the Saiyans”:

Hidden Condition 1: No Saibamen Escape
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Revived Saiyans
#6 – “Invade Earth”:

Hidden Condition 1: Nappa Survives
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Revived Goku
#7 – “Burst Open and Mix!”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 10 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Time Patroller in Training
#8 – “Namekian Dragon Balls”:

Hidden Condition 1: Clear by beating Guldo
Hidden Condition 2: Get 7 Dragon Balls
#9 – “Saiyan Pride”:

Hidden Condition 1: Vegeta’s health > 50 %
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Revived Goku
#10 – “Defeat Frieza’s Army”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 10 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Ginyu, Burter, Jeice
#11 – “Force Entrance Exam”:

Hidden Condition 1: Guldo’s Health > 50%
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Ginyu
#12 – “Fierce Battle! Ginyu Force”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 5 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Frieza
#13 – “Tri-Race Coop”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 5 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Frieza and revived Enemies
#14 – “Legendary Super Saiyan”:

Hidden Condition 1: Defeat Krillin before Goku
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Super Saiyan Goku
#15 – “Explosion of Namek”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 3 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Time Patroller in Training
#16 – “Super Saiyan Legend”:

Hidden Condition 1: Befriend Vegeta and clear with him alive
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Super Saiyan Vegeta
#17 – “Challenge Hercule”:

Hidden Condition 1: Hercule’s Health > 50 %
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Revived Vegeta
#18 – “Return of Ginyu Force!”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 5 min
Hidden condition 2: Defeat Frieza
#19 – “Let’s Train”:

Hidden Condition 1: Clear with Vegeta and Gohan Transformed
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Revived Gohan
#20 – “Multiple Cell Jr. Hunt”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 5 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Cell
#21 – “The Cell Games Begin”:

Hidden Condition 1: Defeat Piccolo and Goku before Gohan
Hidden Condition 2: Win without defeating Cell
#22 – “Earth in Danger”:

Hidden Condition 1: Defeat all enemies
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat all revived enemies
#23 – “Clash! Perfect Cell”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 3 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Revived Cell
#24 – “Power Teams”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 10 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Revived Gohan and Cell
#25 – “17 and 18 of the Official History”:

Hidden Condition 1: Vegeta and Piccolo Survive
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Revived #17 and #18
#26 – “Warrior’s annihilation – Future Chapters”:

Hidden Condition 1: #17 and #18 survive
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Trunks
#27 – “Artifical Warriors”:

Hidden Condition 1: Beat all Cell Juniors
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Cell and revived #17 and #18
#28 – “Take back the Dragon Balls”:

Hidden Condition 1: Beat all Cell Juniors
Hidden Condition 2: Get 7 Dragon Balls
#29 – “2nd World Tournament Tag Team”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 5 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat all enemies
#30 – “Great Saiyaman is here”:

Hidden Condition 1: Great Saiyaman survive
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Revived Frieza and Cell
#31 – “Majin Chaos”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 10 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Buu
#32 – “Super Saiyan Bargain Sale”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 5 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Super Saiyan 3 Goku
#33 – “Namek Berserker”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 5 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Revived Piccolo
#34 – “Majin Revival”:

Hidden Condition 1: Buu’s Health > 50%
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Revived Hercule
#35 – “Tag with Gotenks”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 5 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Ultimate Gohan
#36 – “Majin Banquet”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 5 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Hercule and revived Buu
#37 – “Potara Warrior”:

Hidden Condition 1: Super Buu’s Health > 50%
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Super Vegito
#38 – “Blast the Super Spirit Bomb”:

Hidden Condition 1: Buu Survive
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Revived Kid Buu
#39 – “Cell Games Continued”:

Hidden Condition 1: Defeat Videl and Piccolo before Gohan
Hidden Condition 2: Win without Defeating Cell
#40 – “Stop Beerus’ Destruction”:

Hidden Condition 1: Clear without any ally defeated
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Whis
#41 – “Frieza’s Nightmare Returns”:

Hidden Condition 1: Defeat Gotenks before Vegito
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Super Vegito and Super Saiyan 3 Gotenks
#42 – “Power of a Super Saiyan God”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 3 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Revived Goku
# 43 – “Old Rivals and Dragon Balls”:

Hidden Condition 1: Clear by defeating three enemies
Hidden Condition 2: Get 7 Dragon Balls
#44 – “God of Destruction and his Master”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 5 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat revived Beerus
#45 – “Saiyan Battle”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 5 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Goku and revived Gohan and Vegeta
#46 – “Evil seeks Dragon Balls yet again!”:

Hidden Condition 1: Clear by defeating all enemies
Hidden Condition 2: Get 7 Dragon Balls
#47 – “Super-Super Ultimate series of battles!”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 10 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Vegito and Gotenks
#48 – “Gathering of the Great Evil Alliance”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 10 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat revived Frieza, Cell and Kid Buu
#49 – “Saiyan Revolt”:

Hidden Condition 1: Raditz and Nappa survive
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Vegito
#50 – “Parent and Child”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 10 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Burdock, Raditz and Goku
#51 – “Heated Furious Ultimate Battle”:

Hidden Condition 1: Clear with revived Goku surviving
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat revived Broly
# 52 – “Great Ape Festival”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 10 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat the Time Patroller in training
#53 – “Dangerous Duo! Warriors never rest”:

Hidden Condition 1: Defeat Broly with Gohan surviving
Hidden Condition 2: Get 7 Dragon Balls
# 54 – “Saiyan Warriors”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 10 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat all revived enemies
#55 – “Power Berserkers”:

Hidden Condition 1: < 10 min
Hidden Condition 2: Defeat Gohan, Broly and Bardock
```